# Create tabs from div elements, display another items in one row under

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to create tab-like div elements which have subitems, whenever I click for e.g on row 2 I want another full width row in row 3 with subitems displayed there.

I was thinking of something like 4 items / 1 item / 4items / 1 item and the 1 item is only active whenever div is clicked. But how do I make the 1 item to appear in a proper row and so it takes full width?

Image what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

[image: Image2]

What I've tried so far:

https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a derived/computed state, exposing the items in groups of N (4 in your case). Treating N as variable is going to help on mobile devices (where you're likely to change N's value):

```js
const rows = computed(() => Array.from(
  { length: 1 + items.length / rowSize },
  (_, i) => items.slice(i * rowSize, (i + 1) * rowSize)
));
```

2. `v-for` these computed groups, rendering:
   a) the group items;
   b) the children of the currently open/active item, if the active item is contained in this group

The rest are implementation details:

```js
const {
  createApp,
  computed,
  reactive,
  toRefs,
  nextTick,
  watch,
  onMounted,
  onBeforeUnmount
} = Vue
const { random, round } = Math
const randomBetween = (min, max) => round(random() * (max - min)) + min

createApp({
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      active: null,
      items: Array.from({ length: randomBetween(7, 12) }, (_, i) => ({
        label: `${i + 1}`,
        children: Array.from({ length: randomBetween(2, 7) }, (_, key) => ({
          label: `${i + 1}.${key + 1}`
        }))
      })),
      rowSize: 4,
      rows: computed(() =>
        Array.from(
          { length: 1 + state.items.length / state.rowSize },
          (_, i) =>
            state.items.slice(i * state.rowSize, (i + 1) * state.rowSize)
        )
      ),
      isOpen: (row) => row.map((i) => i.label).includes(state.active),
      select: (id) => {
        state.active = id === state.active ? null : id
      },
      children: computed(
        () =>
          state.items.find((i) => i.label === state.active)?.children || []
      ),
      containerStyle: computed(() => ({
        "--item-width": `calc(${100 / state.rowSize}% - 1rem)`,
        margin: "0 auto",
        maxWidth: 175 * state.rowSize + "px"
      })),
      animators: []
    })
    const updateHeights = () =>
      nextTick(() => {
        state.animators.forEach((el) => {
          el.style.setProperty(
            "--height",
            (el.querySelector("div")?.offsetHeight || 0) + "px"
          )
        })
      })
    watch(() => [state.active, state.rowSize], updateHeights, {
      immediate: true
    })
    onMounted(() => window.addEventListener("resize", updateHeights))
    onBeforeUnmount(() =>
      window.removeEventListener("resize", updateHeights)
    )

    return { ...toRefs(state) }
  }
}).mount("#app")
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#app {
  --transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.4, 1);
  --gap: 0.5rem;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: var(--gap);
}
.row > * {
  flex: 0 0 var(--item-width);
  margin: 0 var(--gap);
  border: 1px solid #e2e4e8;
  aspect-ratio: 1.618;
  padding: var(--gap);
}
.row .selected {
  background-color: #f2f3f5;
  margin-bottom: calc((var(--gap) + 1px) * -1);
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
.children {
  border: 1px solid #e2e4e8;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.children > * {
  margin: var(--gap);
  background-color: #fff;
}
.animator {
  transition:
    max-height var(--transition),
    min-height var(--transition);
  max-height: var(--height);
  min-height: var(--height);
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f2f3f5;
}
.children > * {
  transition: opacity .2s ease .1s, transform .2s ease .1s;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
.list-enter-from {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(.5rem) scale(0.9);
}
.list-leave-to {
  transition-duration: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.39/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Row size: <input type="range" min="2" max="6" step="1" v-model="rowSize" /> {{
  rowSize }}
  <div :style="containerStyle">
    <template v-for="(row, key) in rows" :key="key">
      <div class="row">
        <div
          v-for="({ label }, index) in row"
          :key="index"
          v-text="label"
          @click="select(label)"
          :class="{ selected: label === active }"
        ></div>
      </div>
      <div ref="animators" class="animator">
        <div v-if="isOpen(row)" class="row children">
          <transition
            name="list"
            mode="out-in"
            appear
            v-for="{ label } in children"
          >
            <div :key="label" v-text="label"></div>
          </transition>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
```